# Заглушка для картинки

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, svg

Никак не могу правильно сделать заглушку для картинки. Есть `svg`, которую я хочу размещать везде, где картинка не загрузилась, и только после 100% загрузки страницы начинали бы загружаться сами картинки. Подскажите с чего начать, или статью какую нибудь где это реализовано на практике.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C атрибутом

```html
<img src="bla bla bla"
     onerror="this.src = 'https://i.mycdn.me/image?id=814327925848&t=0&plc=WEB&tkn=*GsdCWAmDvjL9x0vo-r1OjNdHSKY'">
```

На JQuery

```js
$('img').on('error',function(){
  $(this).attr('src', 'https://i.mycdn.me/image?id=814327925848&t=0&plc=WEB&tkn=*GsdCWAmDvjL9x0vo-r1OjNdHSKY');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="asdasd" alt="asd" />
```

Comment: ого, просто и лаконично, то что нужно!!

Comment: Добавил ещё вариант на `jquery`, чтобы во все картинки атрибут не писать.